# bash : cd /Documents not working

Tags: bash, terminal

I dont know what happened, now if I want to `cd` in to Documents fold I need to type `cd Documents`.

Whereas `cd /Documents` tells me

> -bash: cd: /Documents: No such file or directory

What could be causing this?
I did not really change anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a slash in front of a directory name, you mean this directory's located in the root of a file system.

Your error message may mean `Documents` is *not* located there. You should use something like `cd /Users/Name/Documents` or `cd /home/Documents` or smth. like this.